# A lot of errors in classes with constructors and function

Tags: c++, arrays, class, dynamic

Here is the code for my file

```
#include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <cstdio>
 #include <fstream>



 class Sphere{
   private:
     int x;
     int y;
     int r;
   public:
     Sphere();
     void set_x(int first);
     void set_y(int second);
     void set_r(int radius);
     int get_x();
     int get_y();
     int get_r();
 };

 class Array{
   private:
     Sphere** spheres;
     int size;
     int maxsize=101;
   public:
     Array();
     ~Array();
     void addSphere(const Sphere& sphere);
     Sphere& getSphere(int index)const;
     int getQuant(int xp,int yp);
 };

int main(){
  Array spheres;
  for(int i=0;i<101;i++){
    spheres.addSphere(Sphere());
  }
  getQuant(15,30);
  std::cout << "The programm made it to the end" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

Sphere::Sphere(){
  x=rand()%100;
  y=rand()%100;
  r=rand()%50;
}


void Sphere::set_x(int first){
  x=first;
}
void Sphere::set_y(int second){
  y=second;
}
void Sphere::set_r(int radius){
  r=radius;
}
int Sphere::get_x(){
  return x;
}
int Sphere::get_y(){
  return y;
}
int Sphere::get_r(){
  return r;
}

Array::Array():size(0){
  spheres=new Sphere*[maxsize];
}

Array::~Array(){
  for(int i=0;i<maxsize;i++){
    delete spheres[i];
  }
  delete[] spheres;
}


void Array::addSphere( const Sphere& sphere){
  if(size<maxsize){
    spheres[size]=new Sphere();
    size++;
  }else{
    std::cout << "\nThe limit is exceeded at" << size << std::endl;
  }
}
int Array::getQuant(int xp,int yp){
  int quantity;
  for(int i=0;i<101;i++){
    getSphere(i);
    if(this->x <= xp){
      if(this->y <=yp){
        quant++;
      }
    }
  }
  std:cout << "The quantity of spheres that has centers inside the stated area is:" << quantity;
}

Sphere& Array::getSphere(int index)const{
  return *spheres[index];
}
```

Well, this program should work in following way: generate a 101 number of spheres(that's not sphere but it doesn't matter) with random numbers of center coordinates and radius. then it should find the quantity of spheres that have centers in a situated area of coordinates. but i got a lot of errors. here is the text of them.

```
./src/main.cpp:42:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'getQuant'
  getQuant(15,30);
  ^
./src/main.cpp:97:14: error: no member named 'x' in 'Array'
    if(this->x <= xp){
       ~~~~  ^
./src/main.cpp:98:16: error: no member named 'y' in 'Array'
      if(this->y <=yp){
         ~~~~  ^
./src/main.cpp:99:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'quant'
        quant++;
        ^
./src/main.cpp:103:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'cout'; did you mean 'std::cout'?
  std:cout << "The quantity of spheres that has centers inside the stated area is:" << quantity;
      ^~~~
      std::cout
```

can you help me solve them?

Comment: you're calling the methods but not in the context of the object, for example getQuant() instead of spheres.getQuant(); also i would rename Array in something else to avoid name collisions

Comment: Your code is confusing. 1. `x` is private in `Sphere`, so I presume your trying to use `sphere->get_x()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the errors in your original code:

1. In the main function, you did not call that method getQuant() with an object.  You will need to call the getQuant() method with an object to fix that error.
2. First error in the method Array::getQuant()

To compare x with xp, you will need to call `getSphere(i).get_x() <= xp` because your **Array** class does not contain data member x, and only the **Sphere** class contains data member x. So, you will need to access the data member x via the object of the class **Sphere**.

3. Second error in the method Array::getQuant()

   You wrote **"quant++"** but **quant** is defined anywhere. I think you made a typo, and should have typed **"quantity++"** instead.
4. Third error in the method Array::getQuant()

You made a typo when you wrote **std:cout** at the end of that method. The correct syntax is **std::cout**.

=========

Below are my new code in which I've fixed all errors and make sure that the code compiles and runs well

```
int Array::getQuant(int xp,int yp){
  int quantity;
  for(int i=0;i<101;i++){
    //getSphere(i);
    if(getSphere(i).get_x() <= xp){
      if(getSphere(i).get_y() <=yp){
        quantity++;
      }
    }
  }
  std:cout << "The quantity of spheres that has centers inside the stated area is:" << quantity;
}
```

==========

```
int main(){
  Array spheres;
  for(int i=0;i<101;i++){
    spheres.addSphere(Sphere());
  }
  spheres.getQuant(15,30); // I call getQuant() with an object to fix the error
  std::cout << "The programm made it to the end" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

=============

Again, these 2 methods above have been fixed and run correctly as I have verified. Please let me know if you run into any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just follows each error:

> ./src/main.cpp:42:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'getQuant'
> getQuant(15,30);

In main() function, you call `getQuant`, which is part of `Array` class, but you call it as a standalone function (which does not exits).

You probably want:

```
spheres->getQuant(15,30);
```

---

> ./src/main.cpp:97:14: error: no member named 'x' in 'Array'
> if(this->x <= xp){

In `getQuant` implementation, you have `this->x` but `Array` has no `x` member.

---

> ./src/main.cpp:99:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'quant'
> quant++;

In `getQuant` implementation, you have `quant++` but this variable is not declared. Did yo mean `quantity`?

---

> ./src/main.cpp:103:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'cout'; did you mean 'std::cout'?

`cout` is part of `<iostream>` and comes with `std` namespece. You must call `std::cout` or call `using std::cout;`